# How to flip a QCheckBox display

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

The QCheckBox widget has the check box on the left and the description on the right (as seen below):

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to have the description on the left and the box on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QWidget::setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);`.

```
QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox("Hey!", parent);
checkBox->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks Anthony!  Tested and working!

Answer (score 0):

*QWidget::setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);*   won't be working ,QT 4.7 onwards.

Use QApplication::setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);